# Ratio of the 3rd and 1st derivative of a function (polynomial)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

In the course of my work, I found a problem where the ratio between the 3rd and the 1st derivatives of a function is used as some kind of measure of how smooth the function is. The derivatives are computed numerically. If the ratio is large, the function is not smooth enough.

I made several examples to explore this idea, but the point still escapes me. If we take the first derivative as a measure how much function locally deviates from a constant and the third derivative as a measure how much it deviates from a parabola, then the ratio of the two will be large when it does deviate from parabola, but also when the deviation from a constant it small. It seems like a rather ill-defined quantity.

Does this ratio appear in some formal mathematical theory in this context?

Comment: "ill-defined quantity" - Indeed will be. You are comparing the 1st derivative against constant, while you are comparing the 3rd derivative against a parabola. There is no actual comparison to be made here unless you can relate the parabola to the constant, which generates some sort of constant of proportionality. However, the comparisons are different. A parabola ≠ a constant. Maybe consider comparing both the derivates against another constant function or a directrix.

Comment: Indeed. I see no much sense in using that ratio and I wonder if the ratio is used anywhere else. Sorry for not sharing the reference (it's an internal document).

Comment: Does this apply to polynomial functions only?

Answer (score 1):

I got what was the point behind this operator! The purpose of the operator is to identify peaks, thus places where the function is not smooth. A requirement for this operator is to be: positive, dimensionless and definite (and its amplitude is not so important as it is multiplied by a number of factors of which some already involve certain arbitrariness).

An obvious choice for this would be to start from the second derivative as a measure of deviation of the polynomial from linear (perfectly smooth) function:
$$o_1(f) = \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}$$

then we get rid of $dx^2$ as it is constant and it does not contribute to the goal:
$$o_2(f) = \Delta^2 f$$

Then we divide $o_2$ to get rid of the dimension of $f$:
$$o_3(f) = \frac{\Delta^2 f}{f}$$

To make sure that it is positive:
$$o_4(f) = \frac{\Delta^2 |f|}{|f|}$$

In the numerical implementation, this operator is applied to the function that contains numerical errors, and this function is not $f$, but $df/dx$ (i.e. $\Delta f$). So, we apply $o_4$ to $df/dx$ and the result is

$$o_4(\Delta f) = \frac{\Delta^2 |\Delta f|}{|\Delta f|} = \frac{|\Delta^3 f|}{|\Delta f|} = (\Delta x)^2 \frac{|\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}|}{|\frac{df}{dx}|} \sim \frac{|\frac{d^3f}{dx^3}|}{|\frac{df}{dx}|}$$

One still have to take special care of the cases when the first derivative is zero, but the interpretation of the operator makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is what your looking for but maybe this may help:

Let $f$ be a arbitrary function (picked out of a random generator): $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x^{5}+4x^{3}+5x^{2}+3x+2$

Then,

$p(x) = \frac{df(x)}{dx} =5x^{4}+12x^{2}+10x+3$

And

$q(x) = \frac{d^3f(x)}{dx^3} = 60x^{2}+24$

Now let's make a point of comparison. This is arbitrary and could be anything you want as long as its the **same comparison** for both the derivatives. Here, the comparison being the **vertical distance** between the 2 derivatives and a line parallel to the x-axis, or $g(x)=-4$

$dp(x) = \sqrt{(p(x) - g(x))^2}$

$dq(x) = \sqrt{(q(x) - g(x))^2}$

You cannot really tell any similarity unless you plot it:

[image: Comparison]

Notice how the 2 functions visible on the plot ($dp$ and $dq$) look almost parallel to each other (ignoring their minimums), although they are not. This tells that both the 1st and 3rd derivatives have **roughly** the same change in the vertical distance from the line $g(x)$. This also hints towards their gradients of the 1st and 3rd derivative increasing at roughly the same amount per $x$.  If you want a further comparison you could compare the ratios of those gradients, which may reveal something useful. Otherwise, its up to you.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried similar experiment with different functions and, still, I cannot see any point in using this ratio.